# Show SQL generated by Objectify for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

i'm sure there's a way to do this

Does anybody know if there is a way to view the SQL generated by Objectify for Google App Engine (i want to make sure my batch sql statements are working correctly)

I know in Hibernate there's a simple XML key to turn this on - is there anything like this for Objectify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SQL.  The GAE datastore does not use SQL; the Low Level API roughly looks like a "hashmap of hashmaps" with a handful of primitive operations like get, put, delete, and query.

This may help:  http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts

That said, Objectify4 will log a large quantity of information if you enable DEBUG logging for com.googlecode.objectify.  It's a bit like drinking from the firehose.  You won't find SQL, however.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me - what i'm worrying about, i've been using hibernate/jpa, we are just switching over to GAE and are going to start paying for their service, is there anyway while in dev mode to see how many queries i'm using per operation anywhere? I haven't quite gotten to the point yet where I can run a lot since i'm in the middle of a port - sorry if this is a bad question

Comment: Still, it would be very nice, if there would be a switch for Ofy to turn on/off logging of all executed GQL queries.

Comment: There is no GQL involved either.